# tmux config: what is -t in bind-key setting should mean?

Tags: macos, tmux

Suddenly my tmux started with error `.tmux.conf:41: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-T key-table] key command [arguments]`
on that line in tmux.conf was  `bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection`
I suppose, the problem is with -t key, which is not predicted by bind-key command.
But it was working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different types of key table were integrated together and the `-t` flag dropped several years ago. Copy mode commands are now sent using `send -X` and the new table is called `copy-mode-vi`.

So your example becomes:

```
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
```

Comment: where is documentation for bind-key?

Comment: You can also look here https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#key-bindings although it does not cover `send -X` and copy mode much.